# Rectangular lattice and periodic energy/$k$ dispersion

Tags: solid-state-physics, dispersion

Given is a rectangular lattice (a=0.44 nm; b=0.34 nm), Fermi energy of $E_F = 6.4$eV and the energy/k dispersion along $k_a$ with $E(k)=E_0 - E_0 \cos(k\cdot a)$; $E_0 = 4$eV analogous in $k_b$ direction.

My issue is the following:
The wavevectors are defined through $k_a = \frac{\pi}{a}$ analogous for $k_b$. The energy for an electron with the wavevector ($k_a$,0) would be 8 eV according to the erngy/k dispersion. But this is greater than the Fermi energy so this state is not occupied. The energy for an electron with the wavevector ($2 \cdot k_a$,0) would be 0 eV. Since the wavevector is quantised there are no states in between those two along the $k_a$ direction right? Same thing along the $k_b$ direction.
This is kind of weird to me. I would consider that 0 eV energy for an electron is a problem. So from that, I would think that this situation is inconsistent in itself.

I thought that I understood this solid state topic but this task made me doubt it. Is it possible that this situation is inconsistent in itself or am I just missing something? Any type of comment might help me understand this topic better, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different misconceptions in your descriptions--I'll try to address both.

First, while wavevectors are quantized, there are *many* possible values of $\vec{k}$ between the center and edge of the Brillouin zone. The number of states in $k$-space is equal to the number of lattice cells $N$ in the lattice in real space.  Since for most purposes $N$ is on the order of $10^{23}$, for all intents and purposes we can usually treat $k$-space as continuous. Plenty of states will be occupied near the zone center and plenty more will be unoccupied near the zone boundary, where the energy is above $E_F$ as you mentioned.

Second, the 0 eV state is not at all a problem--the choice of a reference energy is largely arbitrary.  Whoever designed this question simply chose to set 0 eV as the bottom of this energy band.  In other problems, different authors may choose to use the Fermi energy as the reference, or even the vacuum level (the potential energy of an electron which is *not* bound to the lattice) in which case *all* of the electrons in the lattice have negative energy.  The only thing that really matters in practical band theory is the differences in energy, since the Pauli exclusion principle will dictate how the band fills in from there based on the electrons available.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Indeed this helps, thank you! but I still have a query. Is there a formula to calculate the possible $\vec{k}$ values between the centre and edge of the Brillouin zone? I thought this would be done by a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{a}$ or is it actually $\frac{\pi}{n a}$ with n = 0,1,2,..., N?

Comment: It is indeed the $\frac{\pi}{na}$ option, $n=1, 2 ..., N$.  There might be a factor of 2 in the denominator--I'm not confident on that (and as I mentioned above, it rarely matters.)  If we start with $N$ non-interacting atoms and each one hosts a single quantum state (an orbital, if we neglect spin) then we will *always* have $N$ possible quantum states, no matter what kind of lattice we assemble them into.  For a periodic lattice, that means we need to cram those $N$ states into the first Brillouin zone.